# Como selecionar variáveis em uma lista pelo maior valor bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Eu tenho um arquivo com umas 20.000 linhas e muitas variáveis com a seguinte estrutura:
GA1 0.768
GA2 0.679
GA3 0.689
GA1 0.890
GA3 0.987
GA2 0.765
Preciso selecionar as linhas pelo maior valor de cada variável e enviar para um único arquivo
Ex

GA1 0.890
GA2 0.765
GA3 0.987

Alguém sabe como consigo fazer isso??

Answer (score 1):

A questão precisava de exemplos melhores. Mas supondo que tenhas um arquivos assim:

```
GA1 0.890
GA2 0.765
GA3 0.987
GA4 0.222
GA0 0.332
GA8 1.232
```

Pode usar o sort pra classificar os valores

```
sort -t" " -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n < arquivo.txt
```

o resultado será esse:

```
GA4 0.222
GA0 0.332
GA2 0.765
GA1 0.890
GA3 0.987
GA8 1.232
```